# Use C/C++ Extension for VS code without any compiler installed

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I want to use the C/C++ Extension for VS code without any compiler installed on the machine. (I don't need a compiler because I compile my code in a docker container).

Problem: In the "Problems" section of VS code I get folllowing errors related to the standard c libraries:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (path_to_file).
cannot open source file "stdint.h" (dependency of "app.h")
```

Any Workarounds or any way to disable those specific errors(standard libraries)?

p.s. I can compile the project successfully.

Comment: The problem for especially **C++** is that it is **unbelievably difficult to parse correctly** and you need to essentially have a **C++ compiler for that alone**.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: It's more than difficult. I can write a reasonable program that you **provably cannot parse** without `stdint.h`. Specifically, any program that uses template instantiations which depend on `stdint.h` cannot be parsed.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers You can move most to the container

Comment: Did you consider installing [Debian](http://debian.org/) on your laptop computer?

Comment: @MSalters: Interesting. Do you have a working example on the web?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: As a simple example, reasonable programs may reference `std::numeric_limits<std::intmax_t>::digits`. That obviously requires `std::intmax_t` in order to look up the correct specialization. And if you don't know that `std::intmax_t` is a type, because you lack `<cstdint>`, then you don't know that `digits` is a integral constant expression.

Comment: @MSalters what I meant is that even if you have the headers then there are not many parsers for C++ that actually work for any decent definition and do not come with a compiler

Comment: @LexLi I need to debug embedded projects with a usb programmer within VS code. As far I know it's not possible to pass through a USB device to a Docker container running Docker for windows.

Comment: Btw I only need it to work with C

Answer (score 2):

You need at least a standard library to have "intelli-sense".
You can download for example [libc++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html) or MS-STL only.

Another option would be to use the std headers stored in your docker container.
Here you can find some docs to customize your include path: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference

What is the reason you don't want to install a compiler on your local machine?

Comment: It would be perfect to use the std headers stored in the docker container. But it's still unclear how to achieve that.

Comment: About your question.. I want be able to quickly start working on a new machine without the need of installing a bunch of programs/toolchain. Ideally I just install VS code and docker and the rest is in the docker container